# cpio is not working properly in repacking initrd.lz for live

Tags: linux, ubuntu, initrd, live-cd

If I unpack `initrd.lz` and then repack it without making any changes, then replace it with my new initrd.lz in Casper directory for live CD. It is structed. While packing of initrd I got a warning message as below:

> cpio: ./usr/share/plymouth/themes/text.plymouth: Cannot stat: No such file or directory.

Finally my question is, what is the utility to pack and unpack the `initrd.lz`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the contents of the initrd:

```
  mkdir temp
  cd temp
  lzma -dc -S .lz /mnt/casper/initrd.lz | cpio -id
```

Modify and Repack them into a new initrd:

```
  find . | cpio --quiet --dereference -o -H newc | lzma -7 > ~/new-initrd.lz
```

and for the text.plymouth check if the file is present

Comment: Thanks for giving suggestion,                                                                        text.plymouth and default.plumouth is not present after repacking of initrd.lz. Suggest me what i need to do now?

Comment: I have added my Plymouth theme here temp/usr/share/plymouth/themes
and if you don't add them you will get a warning but it will work

Comment: Dear @xeon zolt this above procedure is working good on `ubuntu-14.04` but not `ubuntu-16.04`. in `16.04` got error like **udevadm:error while loading shared libraries libcgmanager.so.0 :cannot open shared object file :no such file or directory**, then could not find the installation files/custom.This could also happen if the file system is not clean because of an system crash,an interrupted boot process.                              Thanks,